Differences in nikkud between Ashkenazi Hebrew (or Yiddish?) and "Standard" Hebrew words
I have an interest in Judaism through the prism of Yiddish (specially Hasidic) culture. I'm more proficient in Yiddish but I'm slowly absorbing a bit of Hebrew. Looking through texts edited by Hasidic publishers, Modern Hebrew reference tools, Aramaic reference books in Yiddish, etc, I noticed that there are differences in the nikkud of some words. For example, in the Barditchever Siddur and in a recent Siddur from the Ateres publisher, the words כך and ברכת appear as כַּך and בִּרְכַת instead of כָּך and בִּרְכַּת. In both cases, the difference in nikkud would mean a difference in any Ashkenazi pronunciation that I know of.
My question is if these difference in nekudos that I'm associating with Ashkenazi Hebrew or Yiddish are valid ways of pronouncing these words for things like davening, bentching and leining, or if these forms are "wrong". I think it's interesting to apply this question to two different sets of words:
1 - Words that appear in Tanach;
Like פֶּסַח and not בִּרְכַּת, פֵּסַח and not בִּרְכַת.
2 - Words that do not appear in Tanach but do appear in the Talmud, Siddur, etc.
For example, תֵּיכֶּף-תֵּיכֶף, כָּך-כַּך, סְתַּם-סְתָם.

You’ve seen פסח written vowelized as פֵּסַח?

@JoelK I've seen it with a tzeire in the decoration of some event when seeing the news on AhBlickLive.com.

Interesting. I’m no expert, but I think that’s simply a mistake, probably caused by the pronunciation (in many Hasidic sects) of a segol as “ey” (which most non-Hasidic ashkenazim would use as the sound for tsere).
